How to increase EWS search-mailboxes results more than 100
I use EWS to perform searches on mailboxes. My account is at discovery management group. When I try to search mailboxes with filter "from: and subject:'' " with a mail scope of 500 mailboxes, I only get 100 result. I increased "DiscoveryMaxStatsSearchMailboxes" throttling policy 100 to 500. But still i only get 100 results.
Is there anyone faced and solved this problem?
I increased "DiscoveryMaxStatsSearchMailboxes" throttling policy 100 to 500 but it still does not work.

What's the error your getting ? It can take time for changes to take affect (a restart always helps) if you getting throttled the EWS logs should reflect that.

@GlenScales If I understood the question correctly there is no error besides the results still being limited to 100 instead of 500 even though the Limit in the Throttle policy has been increased.

you should be getting some type of response, if its the same throttling response but you have increased the limit it point to the change not having taken affect. To test you should really start at 101 rather then 500 as you may hit other limits enforced in the web.config https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/client-message-size-limits?view=exchserver-2019 like maxAllowedContentLength (unlikely but i would include it in the mix if 101 works but 499 fails)
